# How to configure index.jsp file with app.json in Extjs 6

Tags: extjs, cmd

Structure of my Application:

[image: Structure of my Application]

In my app.json file I did following configuration for pointing to index.jsp file

```
"indexHtmlPath": "../../iris_app.war/WEB-INF/views/jsp/app/index.jsp",
"output": {
  "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",
  "page": {
    "path": "index.jsp",
    "enable": true
  },
  "manifest": "${build.id}.json",
  "js": "${build.id}/app.js",
  "appCache": {
    "enable": false
  },
  "resources": {
    "path": "${build.id}/resources",
    "shared": "resources"
  }
},
```

When I refresh my app using sencha app refresh it updates classic.json file
With following paths

```
{"paths":
    {
        "Dimension":"../../../../../iris_s.war/regshoapp/app/view/components/popups/SelectDimensionsWindow.js",
"Ext":"../../../../../iris_s.war/ext/classic/classic/src",
"Ext.AbstractManager":"../../../../../iris_s.war/ext/packages/core/src/AbstractManager.js",
"Ext.Ajax":"../../../../../iris_s.war/ext/packages/core/src/Ajax.js"
```

….etc.

When I deployed this application on server and run on browser then I use this
url
    localhost:7001/iris_ops_app/

When I run application on browser it throws file not found error on console for each Ext File which is mentioned in “classic.json” file but these files exist under “http://localhost:7001/iris_ops_app/regshoapp” path.

Please let me know how can I resolve this path issue on browser. Actually “iris_s.war” should be replaced by “iris_ops_s/regshoapp” in “classic.json” file only then it will resolve all paths.

Comment: Not only does console throw an error, it also shows from which urls it tried to download these files. So you can investigate the console a little bit and fix your code appropriately.

Comment: do you find a solution ? i m asking solutions in the same theme here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634461/stack-extjs-6-spring-boot